# In Keyforge, what happens to the Æmber on a creature that is archived?

Tags: keyforge

[Vezyma Thinkdrone](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/2-aoa/cards/172-vezyma-thinkdrone) lets a player archive his creature which is in play (not on his hand). If in this case there is Æmber on that creature, what happens to it? Will the archiving player get it, or his opponent, or is it just discarded?

*Capture* rule says:

> When a creature with Æmber on it leaves play, the Æmber is placed in the opponent’s Æmber pool.

So if a creature is archived from play, does this mean it "leaves play", and therefore the opponent will receive the Æmber on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All the Æmber currently on that creature will go to the opponent's pool.**

---

From [Keyforge's Rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f9/a2/f9a28865-cd96-4f36-97e5-0f8ea75288c0/keyforge_rulebook_v9-compressed.pdf)

The glossary for **Leaves Play** reads (ellipses and emphasis mine):

> If a card that is in play leaves play (is returned to hand or deck, destroyed, discarded, **archived**, or purged), all **non-Æmber tokens** and status cards on the card are removed, [...].
>
> If **a creature with Æmber on it leaves play, the Æmber is placed in the opponent’s Æmber pool**. If a non-creature card with Æmber on it leaves play, the Æmber is returned to the general token pool.

Therefore, all the Æmber on a creature will be placed in your opponent's Æmber pool when it leaves play, not only when it's captured.